showing the sum of the digits in JS
I get a number from the user and i want to calculate the sum of its digits. here's the code:
let num = Number(prompt("Enter a number to see the sum of its digits:"));
if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("please enter a number");
} else {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + num[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
    alert("The result is : " + sum);
}

the program resulted in 0 number as the sum of digits and it's, it's just not working

[...num.toString()].filter(a => a !== ".").map(Number).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)

your problem is here you have a number not a string so you can not have a length

You are converting the prompt input to a number and then trying to loop through the number as if it was an array (which it is not). Instead, leave the input as a string and loop over that array-like object and only convert the individual digits when doing the math.


let num = prompt("Enter a number to see the sum of its digits:");

// Just check for input at this point. Doesn't matter yet if it's a number or not.
if (!num) {
    alert("please enter a number");
} else {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        // The prepended + is an implicit way to convert a string to a number
        sum = sum + +num[i];
    }
    console.log(sum);
    alert("The result is : " + sum);
}




The reason it's not working is because, during the loop, you're basically treating num as if it was a string, but it's actually always a number.
Here's a working code (without changing too much of your code):


let num = Number(prompt("Enter a number to see the sum of its digits:"));
if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("please enter a number");
} else {
    const numString = num.toString(); // Convert it to a string
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < numString.length; i++) {
        // Convert the char (string) to a number to make the sum work
        sum = sum + Number(numString.charAt(i));
    }
    console.log(sum);
    alert("The result is : " + sum);
}



Note: in this case, .charAt() may be a little safer than the bracket notation, because it always returns a string (here's a detailed explanation).

You cannot iterate on a variable which is of number type.
The correct code will be :-


let num = prompt("Enter a number to see the sum of its digits:");
if (isNaN(num)) {
    alert("please enter a number");
} else {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        sum = sum + Number(num[i]);
    }
    console.log(sum);
    alert("The result is : " + sum);
}




That is not  the answer the OP wants. He wants the sum of the number digit.  the correct answer is Scott Marcus's one or Gianluca 's one. In your case you need to use parseFloat() as well

The issue is in how you're trying to access individual digits of a number
let num = Number(prompt("Enter a number to see the sum of its digits:"));
if (isNaN(num)) {

    alert("Please enter a number");
} 

else 

{
    
let sum = 0;
    
let numStr = num.toString();

for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) 
{
        
sum += parseInt(numStr[i]);
   
 }
    
console.log(sum);
    
alert("The result is: " + sum);
}


function sumOfDigit(num) {
return num.toString().split("")
    .reduce((sum, digit) =>
        sum + parseInt(digit), 0);
}

